# count multi-column after using group by

Tags: sql

I'm doing some counting in my query

[image]

I need by count FLOW_ID  twice in different conditions after group by :

```
select count(distinct flow_id) as work_sum,
       count(distinct case when ISHANDLE=2 THEN FLOW_ID) AS ERROR_SUM
       FROM Table A group by ALERT_USER
```

The first column is to count the distinct flow_id,
the second is to count the distinct flow_id where column ISHANDLE =2

but my sql does not work, any one can help ? tks

BTW:I Know I can write two sqls and join the result, but I have another similar columns like this , that will be too lengthy

Comment: Your `CASE` statement is missing an `END`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly correct, needed to `end` the `case`.

```
select count(distinct flow_id) as work_sum,
       count(distinct (case when ISHANDLE=2 THEN FLOW_ID END)) AS ERROR_SUM
       FROM Table A group by ALERT_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF function.

```
select count(distinct flow_id) as work_sum,
       count(distinct IF(ISHANDLE=2, FLOW_ID, NULL)) as ERROR_SUM

FROM
    Table as A
GROUP BY
    ALERT_USER
```

Comment: Try? I think 'if' function is more comfortable and easy.

Comment: Only MySQL uses `IF()` even `IF` with `THEN`. The nearest other I can think of is MS Access' `IIF()`. Did OP confirm the RDMS used?